# Insert a vector (array 1D) into array two-dimensional?

Tags: python, arrays, vector

how can I insert a vector (array 1D)  into an array two-dimensional python?

I have a code generate array one dimension each time length =11, and i want to save this vector in array two dimensions (i,11)
i represent the number of rows, and 11 represent the column

please any suggestion

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example of your code, thanks!

Comment: You're probably looking for np.vstack.

Comment: What module are you using to create these vectors and arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem and the solution bellow.

```
from array import *
import numpy as np
col_num=4
row_num=4
multi_list = [[0 for col in range(col_num)] for row in range(row_num)]
b=np.array([1,2,3,4])

a=np.array([0,0,0,0])


for row in range(row_num):
    for col in range(col_num):
        multi_list[row][col]= b[col]




for col in range(col_num):
    for row in range(row_num):
        a[col]= a[col]+multi_list[row][col]
```